# Example of functions that grow faster than the exponential functions and/or factorial functions?

Tags: functions

What is example of functions that grow faster than the exponential functions and/or factorial functions?

Comment: $x\mapsto \exp (\exp (x ) )$

Comment: $e^{e^x}$ and $e^{x!}$ are two.

Comment: How do you do up arrows in LaTeX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [busy beaver function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver) can be shown to grow faster than any computable function.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy .... Can you tell me proof of that?

Comment: @JamieLolingner I do not know the proof of it's asymptotic domination of computable functions. The fact that it is uncomputable follows from the fact if it were, it would solve the halting problem which is known to be undecidable. A different proof is given in that wiki article. The paper where there is a proof is Radó 1962.

Comment: I believe this is the paper: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=321270

Answer (score 1):

Here there is an example:
$$
x\rightarrow x^x
$$

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting functions that grow faster than exponential is Ackermann function $\mathrm{A}\left(m, n\right)$.  Tetration $x \mapsto {^{n}x} = \underbrace{x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^{x}}}}}_n$ is a special case of Ackermann function.  Tetration is to exponentiation what exponentiation is to multiplication. I.e. iterated exponentiation leads to tetration. A fun fact about tetration: $^44 > $ googolplex.